# Is AccountsJS still useable today?

Tags: javascript, oauth, graphql, google-oauth, mern

I'll try to implement their google oauth strategy but the repo is 3-year old already and do not support update(?) I'm yung MERN-Graphql. Can someone guide me to the right documentation? Also, most of the dependecy used are depricated.

I want to implement their google oauth strategy on my project. But, most of the packages they used are depricated.